Нужна ли запятая после "Арбат"?
Жили мы в основном в Москве, на знаменитой улице Арбат в течение пяти лет.

Ответ дополнен относительно авторского решения, то есть желания что-то обособлять или нет. Такой выбор должен быть осознанным и чем-то обоснованным.
Возможны два варианта:
(1) Жили мы в основном в Москве на знаменитой улице Арбат в течение пяти лет.
(2) Жили мы в основном в Москве, на знаменитой улице Арбат, в течение пяти лет.
Пояснение

В общем случае обстоятельства места могут считаться неоднородными (город и улица), но второе обстоятельство также можно считать уточняющим по отношению к первому (сужение значения, где именно).

Выбор по контексту. В первом случае дается полная информация, которая одинаково важна и будет использована в текущем тексте. Это скорее тема именно Арбата.

Во втором случае место проживания только уточняется,  а основной информацией по ближайшему фрагменту текста считается город Москва. То есть дальше следует московская тема.



А почему не возможен вариант с одной запятой после "Москвы"?

Можно ответить так: у нас три обстоятельства, два обстоятельства места + обстоятельство времени.  В такой последовательности нельзя считать два первых однородными, а третье неоднородным по отношению к первым двум. Но вы спросите – а почему нельзя? Тогда давайте так: ставим одну запятую и смотрим, что получится. А получается, что вся вторая часть уточняет первую, в том числе по интонации. Но такое "уточнение" выглядит странно.

Хотите уточнить, где именно в Москве, - закрывайте.
Жили мы в основном в Москве, на знаменитой улице Арбат, в течение пяти лет.
Хотите рассказать, где жили в течение пяти лет, - знаки не нужны.
Жили мы в основном в Москве на знаменитой улице Арбат в течение пяти лет.

А почему нельзя поставить одну запятую после Москвы? Там обычное перечисление

Я живу в Москве на Фортунатовской. Захочу дать улицу уточнением к городу - поставлю. Просто сообщаю адрес - ничего не нужно.
